# How to convert floats to IntegerType using StructType in PySpark?

Tags: python, types, pyspark

I am trying to create a Spark data frame from a Pandas data frame, where I specify the column data types using StructType class. I've saved the pandas data frame as df and the spark data frame as data.

Before I get into any of that, there's an error somewhere in the csv file, I made use of pandas' read_csv method's parameter, error_bad_lines. I'm unfamiliar with a spark equivalent.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('Amazon_Responded_Oct05.csv',error_bad_lines=False)
df.head()
>>>>
    user_id_str user_followers_count    text_
0   143515471.0 1503    @AmazonHelp Can you please DM me? A product I ...
1   85741735.0  149569  @SeanEPanjab I'm sorry, we're unable to DM you...
2   143515471.0 1503    @AmazonHelp It was purchased on... 
3   143515471.0 1503    @AmazonHelp I am following you now, if it help...
4   85741735.0  149569  @SeanEPanjab Please give us a call/chat so we ...
```

Notice how the user_id_str column is populated with float values, ie 143515471.0 Below is where the error is raised.

```py
data_schema = [StructField('user_followers_count',IntegerType(),True),
               StructField('user_id_str',StringType(),True),
               StructField('text',StringType(),True)]
final_struc = StructType(fields=data_schema)

data = spark.createDataFrame(df,schema=final_struc)
>>>>
TypeError: field user_followers_count: IntegerType can not accept object 143515471.0 in type <class 'float'>
```

I've tried to remedy this from the pandas end without success

```py
df.astype({'user_id_str': 'int','user_followers_count':'int','text_':'str'}).dtypes
df.head(1)
>>>>
    user_id_str user_followers_count    text_
0   143515471.0 1503    @AmazonHelp Can you please DM me? A product I ...
```

In summary, I've taken various approaches to my goal, creating a Spark data frame with column data types, IntegerType, IntegerType, StringType without success. I'd much appreciate a way to force this data conversion.

Edit:

Lastly, I've tried simply starting with Spark; but that was also unfruitful.

```py
data_1 = spark.read.csv('Amazon_Responded_Oct05.csv',schema=final_struc,enforceSchema=True)
data_1.head(5)
>>>>
+--------------------+-----------+----+
|user_followers_count|user_id_str|text|
+--------------------+-----------+----+
|                null|       null|null|
|                null|       null|null|
|                null|       null|null|
|                null|       null|null|
|                null|       null|null|
+--------------------+-----------+----+
only showing top 5 rows
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert from pandas dataframe to pyspark dataframe, try this

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, StringType, IntegerType

#create a sample pandas dataframe
data = {'a':['hello', 'hi', 'world'], 'b':[5.0, 6.4, 9.7], 'c':[1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
'''
    a       b       c
0   hello   5.0     1
1   hi      6.4     2
2   world   9.7     3
'''

#convert second column type to integer
df = df.astype({'b':'int'})
df
'''
    a       b       c
0   hello   5       1
1   hi      6       2
2   world   9       3
'''

#prepare the schema
fields = [StructField('a',StringType(),True),\
               StructField('b',IntegerType(),True),\
               StructField('c',IntegerType(),True)]
schema = StructType(fields)


#convert to a pyspark dataframe
rows = [Row(**_) for _ in df.to_dict(orient='records')]
#[Row(a='hello', b=5, c=1), Row(a='hi', b=6, c=2), Row(a='world', b=9, c=3)]
df_sp = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema)
df_sp.show()
# +-----+---+---+
# |    a|  b|  c|
# +-----+---+---+
# |hello|  5|  1|
# |   hi|  6|  2|
# |world|  9|  3|
# +-----+---+---+
```

Comment: It doesn’t look like your answer addresses converting float types to integer types using StructType..

Comment: @mjake Have a look at my edited answer. Run it, then you will understand it enough to adapt it for your example. Your user_id_str is still printing xxxx.0, if you have converted to an interger successfully, that shouldn't have happened.